# Remove subdirectory name from Magento url

Tags: .htaccess, magento, mod-rewrite

I have Magento installed in a subdirectory, the path to Magento is 'public_html/magento'. I need to keep the Magento instal away from the root for good reasons.

I have a .htaccess file in the root, 'public_html' as follows:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{http_host} ^alisonclairenaturalbeauty.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.alisonclairenaturalbeauty.com/$1 [R=301,L] 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   ^(www\.)?alisonclairenaturalbeauty\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/magento(/.*)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$         /magento/$1    [QSA,L]
```

In the standard Magento .htaccess in 'public_html/magento' I have uncommented the RewriteBase directive as follows:

```
RewriteBase /magento/
```

In the Magento configuration, my unsecure url is 'http://www.alisonclairenaturalbeauty.com/' and my secure one is 'https://www.alisonclairenaturalbeauty.com/'.

My aim is two fold:

1. I want to remove the subdirectory name from the url, so that 'http://www.alisonclairenaturalbeauty.com/magento/' is displayed as 'http://www.alisonclairenaturalbeauty.com' in the browser.
2. I do not want duplicate urls, so the 'real' url 'http://www.alisonclairenaturalbeauty.com/magento/*' must be displayed as 'http://www.alisonclairenaturalbeauty.com/*'.

I have achieved the first aim, but not the second. Unfortunately, my website pages can be accessed by both 'http://www.alisonclairenaturalbeauty.com/skin-care/hand-creams.html' and 'http://www.alisonclairenaturalbeauty.com/magento/skin-care/hand-creams.html'.

I want 'http://www.alisonclairenaturalbeauty.com/magento/skin-care/hand-creams.html' to be rewritten to 'http://www.alisonclairenaturalbeauty.com/skin-care/hand-creams.html'.

I have gone through the posts on SO and also any I can find on Google, but to no avail, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I ended up taking the path of least resistance and moving it into the root.